# reinstall windows Xp without CD but with the cd key

Tags: windows, windows-xp, operating-system, license-key

Is there a legal way to re-install windows XP without the cd but I have the cd key. I would like to download a legal ISO image but I can't find one. There is no image of windows already installed on my computer by the way.

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: where else on stackExchange can I post it? ServerFault is for Server admins

Comment: I'm not sure it necessarily belongs on any of the StackExchange sites. If I had to choose one, I'd say probably SuperUser, but like I said, I think it's better suited for elsewhere, since it seems like your problem can be solved by something like "Download it (not entirely reputably) here: [link provided]".

Comment: Valamas , windows is installed but the manufacturer didn't put an installation image of windows on an other recovery partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you have a MSDN developer login, you won't be able to find those ISOs "legally" (or directly from Microsoft). Just download one from "disreputable" sources, and install using your CD key. Nothing wrong with that, as long as you don't crack the OS, or are using a stolen key.

Comment: are you sure I wont have any trouble downloading it outside Microsoft? If so, can you tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Nick, Renan is referring the to Microsoft Developer Network. You have to be a partner to be able to login and download the ISO from them. You WILL need a CD key. If you are re-installing, there are tools that can tell you which CD key your copy was installed with in case you have lost the paper form or whatever.

Comment: @Valamas I don't have a MSDN license but I HAVE a valid windows xp cd key. I only want to know if i'll have trouble after installing windows from an ISO with my valid cd key (but the ISO doesn't come from Microsoft)

Comment: Lol, sorry mate. I mis-read that you don't have a key when you do.

Answer (score 0):

Is your CD key not working because it is an OEM key? This is, a key that is locked to a computer you bought. For example: I cant buy a dell, then install windows on another computer with the windows key that came with that machine.

Comment: I didn't test it yet, I only want to know if i'll have trouble after installing windows from an ISO with my valid cd key (but the ISO doesn't come from Microsoft)

Comment: Well, backup your data and try it out. My answer states the most probable cause if it is not accepted. If your key is valid, it will reinstall windows with any valid ISO. This is because your key is verified over the internet once you are in your new windows.